# Wifi not working after installing ubuntu 18.04 and 19.10 in Raspberry PI 4

Tags: raspberrypi

I recently installed the latest version of **Ubuntu IOT** for **Raspberry Pi 4** (Ubuntu Server 19.10.1 and Ubuntu 18.04) and am experiencing difficulties accessing some of the on board features. I am not able to use Wifi/Bluetooth/3.5mm Audio or HDMI audio. Does anyone have suggestions to fix this. I have this issue on both of my Raspberry Pi 4's.